# Is switching a dll file enough to update a published ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I've got an ASP.NET application on the server which I can't compile again currently (until some repairs are done). In the meantime though it would be good if I could update a .dll it uses.
So the application bin folder on the published server looks like this (names are abbreviations):

```
myapplication.dll
funcdll1.dll
funcdll2.dll
```

Now a collegue of mine said it should work that I switch out the funcdll1.dll vs. a new version of the same dll (same functions that the myapplciaiton.dll uses, but the underlay for these functions (an external dll that is integrated into that one) is completely new.

So I tried switched the dll out, stopped the application pool and started it again, but seemingly no change to the executed program (it still behaves in the old way). "The old way" is that a database command does not work as the password for the database has changed (which is corrected in the new .dll).

Now I'm wondering if it is possible to do this this way? Or if I did something wrong?

Edit:
As it was asked: The applicaiton itself is a webservice, where non asp.net programs connect to and execute the functions and get the results back (all via https naturally).
The password is directly in the .dll without any web.config file (additionally there were some mandatory optimizations in the .dll from what I know).

Comment: Why are you embedding database passwords in a DLL is probably the more important question...

Comment: can you provide more details of the app, a web app? password in web.config?

Comment: Did you clear cache?

Comment: I think it depends on how is integrated your application, sometimes for example, if your are using a dependency injection through a config file instead of creating them in the code, just changing the config file with the names work, because everything is plugged correctly, in other case you need to compile the code if your dependencies and methods have a new overload. Changing the webconfig and saving it, has the same effect of restarting the application. Once the IIS notice a change on your config, it stops the applicaction and restart, then you can check if your changes are taking effect

Comment: @mason the pw is directly in the .dll itself (the design choice was not mine). I only mentioned it for completeness sake what hte main difference is (in addition to updated code).

Comment: @JerrySwitalski  you mean the recycle command in the application pool? (shouldnt that the stop and start do also)

Comment: @Jeb50  updated the question.  and no no.config file the pw is directly in the .dll (program code). additionally some optimizations are also in that code and its all in the .dll itself.

Comment: @Thomas this too, but also so trivial thing like browser cache. EDIT: but I see now it is webservice.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski in this case as its another program that accesses the .asp.net file there is (at least) no "client" cache that can be /needs to be cleared.

Comment: IIS may have your dll cached, have you tried to recycle IIS?

Comment: @kevin I even tried an iisreset in the meantime (so should be recycled) yes but sadly to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Simple dll replacement should work.
one more question is how you 'switch the dll out'.
Do not copy or rename it. Paste new and choose overwrite.
If you need a backup - archive the 'bin' folder.
Also iisreset or server restart might be an option to try (though it should not be required).

Comment: I overwrote and stopped/started the application pool, but didn't do an iisreset. good point there! will try that one out tomorrow. tnx.

Comment: no sadly did not work (tried it out including iisreset).

Comment: Not sure if you fixed it already. U can try creating a myapplilcation.config xml file and place it inside bin folder (change names and version numbers).

<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration>     
    <runtime>        
        <assemblyBinding xmlns = "urn:schemas­microsoft­com:asm.v1" >
            < dependentAssembly >
                < assemblyIdentity name="funcdll1" culture="neutral"/> 
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion = "1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />         
            </dependentAssembly>      
        </assemblyBinding>    
    </runtime>  
</configuration>